# ScrollPane used with PaintSurface

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, graphics2d

I'm making an attempt at making a mini paint program.
I'm trying to have scroll bars and a paint surface in a JPanel (paint surface in the center, scroll bars on south and east)

```
    CPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JScrollPane horiPane = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JScrollPane vertiPane = new JScrollPane(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    CPanel.add(horiPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
    CPanel.add(vertiPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);      
    PaintSurface p = new PaintSurface();
    p.setPreferredSize(dim);
    CPanel.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Problem is when I resize it, it just resizes the paint surface and the JPanel to fix the new size instead of allowing for scrolling

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the JScrollPane incorrectly. The basic code is:

```
PaintSurface paintSurface = new PaintSurface();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( paintSurface );
cPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Start by reading the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for the basics of using all Swing components.